# SELECT TO_NUMBER('MUST_BE_SAME_TIMEZONE_FILE_VERSION')

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, oracle-11g, rman, sysdba

I upgrade Oracle from 11.1.0.6.0 (32bit version) to 11.2.0.1.0 (64bit version) using RMAN on the same Windows computer (64bit).

After RMAN restored and recovered, I then try to run

```
SQL> startup upgrade;
SQL> @?/admin/catupgrd.sql
```

I got the following errors:

```
SELECT TO_NUMBER('MUST_BE_SAME_TIMEZONE_FILE_VERSION')
ERROR at line 1: ORA-01722: invalid number
```

My timezone version is

```
SELECT version FROM v$timezone_file;
timezlrg_11.dat VERSION: 11

select * from sys.registry$database;
Microsoft Windows IA (32-bit)
TZ_VERSION: 4
```

Comment: Did you run preupgrade checks?

Comment: no, how to run and is it possible to run that now

Comment: Most probably time zone needs to be patched  but start database normally with 32 bit binaries and run preupgrade checks with `utlu111i.sql` from 64 bit new oracle home but in the end you need Oracle support for patches.

Comment: thanks for your info but currently, I don't have Oracle support account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally resolve this error by using DBUA but I got errors in this step, then I returned to restore from RMAN again then everything just works